# SQL Server transaction, error when ordering a select result set

Tags: sql-server

I cannot order a results set returned from a transaction.

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

My code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT MenuItemID
           FROM dbo.Menu_Items_Custom
           WHERE PodID = 288 )
BEGIN
    (SELECT 
         C.MenuItemID,
         ISNULL(NewName, ItemName) AS ItemName,
         ISNULL(URL, ItemURL) AS ItemURL,
         M.Type,
         C.OrderBy
     FROM      
         Menu_Items_Custom C
     LEFT JOIN 
         Menu_Items M ON M.MenuItemID = C.MenuItemID
     WHERE     
         (ChildOf IS NULL AND PodID = 288)
     ORDER BY  
         C.OrderBy);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM dbo.Menu_Items
     WHERE ChildOf IS NULL);
END;
```

Comment: Sorry orderBy is a field.

Comment: Nope, no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to wrap your `SELECT` in parentheses, also remove the 2 extra semicolon:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  MenuItemID
            FROM    dbo.Menu_Items_Custom
            WHERE   PodID = 288 )
    BEGIN
        SELECT    C.MenuItemID ,
                    ISNULL(NewName, ItemName) AS ItemName ,
                    ISNULL(URL, ItemURL) AS ItemURL ,
                    M.Type ,
                    C.OrderBy
          FROM      Menu_Items_Custom C
                    LEFT JOIN Menu_Items M ON M.MenuItemID = C.MenuItemID
          WHERE     (ChildOf IS NULL
                    AND PodID = 288)
          ORDER BY  C.OrderBy

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT    *
        FROM      dbo.Menu_Items
        WHERE     ChildOf IS NULL
    END;
```

Comment: @JamesL. No, because it deos not include an `ORDER BY`, but yeah no need tow leave them there :). The `ORDER BY` clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, **subqueries**, and common table expressions **unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.**

Comment: @chris Please [see this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/343089)